# What is the rarity of poisons within the DMG?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting, poison

I’m currently working on an Artificer build, upon reaching level 10 Artificer’s receive the following ability.

> ## Magic Item Adept
>
> When you reach 10th level, you achieve a profound understanding of how to use and make magic items:
>
> - You can attune to up to four magic items at once.
> - If you craft a magic item with a rarity of common or uncommon, it takes you a quarter of the normal time, and it costs you half as much of the usual gold.

After looking on page 258 of the DMG in the section that mentions harvesting and creating poisons, I cannot find anything that mentions the rarity of said poisons in either the DMG or in D&D Beyond, does anyone have a RAW answer to the rarities of poisons? Please include any sourcebook use and do not interpret rarity based on creature type as that is extremely campaign dependent and will not shed light onto the main issue I’m having.

If no RAW answer is available I will accept the best interpretation of the rules that site sources as well as using logic to dictate their resulting answer.

Comment: What makes you think the feature has anything to do with poisons?

Comment: @V2Blast I thought it would because you can create Poisons.

Comment: Related question: [How does crafting poisons work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67951/how-does-crafting-poisons-work)

Comment: I know, I brought that page up in my question.

Comment: It's just a link to a related question on RPG.SE itself. I'm not saying it's a duplicate. And you're right that the answer to it does reference the same page of the DMG mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Poisons are not magic items so they have no rarity

Poisons can be made (or bought) at any time by any character although it helps if you are proficient with and have a [poisoner’s kit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/poisoners-kit).